# jQuery: change visual output of checkbox to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

When I loop over all checkboxes with class .category attached and try to change the visual output of the checkbox to checked, nothing happens. Variable 'state' returns true or false and is used to change the element it's current visual output. At this very moment nothing happens and I don't know why.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="category">checky 1</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="category">checky 2</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="category">checky 3</span>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click','.category',click);

function click(){
  $('.category').each(function(i,element){
    var state = $(element).prop('checked');
    $(element).prop('checked', state);
  });

  return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *At this very moment nothing happens and I don't know why.* -- what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: I expect the clicked checkbox to output a visual check. At this moment it still looks unchecked, even when checked.

Comment: What is this meant to do? You're reading the state of the element, and then setting the element to the same state. Nothing can happen. Really, you need to add your relevant HTML to this question and then clearly explain, step-by-step, what does, and should, happen.

Comment: Good point, but why it doesn't change visually then?

Comment: @user2381011 See my answer. From what I see you're trying to implement select all option.

Comment: `return false;` prevents default behaviour of checking a checkbox

Comment: @A.Wolff Wolff Golden tip, I removed the return false and all works fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that nothing happens because you're using `return false` in event handler. That will prevent (un)checking the checkbox.

If you're trying to implement *Select All* option, just do:

```js
$(".category:first").on("click", function() {
  $(".category").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/> Select all</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/></label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/></label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/></label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/></label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/></label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category"/></label><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set your checkboxes checked.

```
$('body').on('click','.category',click);

function click(){
  $('.category').each(function(i,element){
    element.value='checked';
  });

  return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of it? I don't get it

Comment: I hope your kidding, but just in case your not.
1) It adds an click event-listener to every .category element.
2) The function iterates over all the .category elements.
3) and sets their value to checked.

Comment: Sorry, i was talking about it: `element.value='checked';` What is the purpose of setting value of a checkbox to 'checked'?

Comment: Every input has a value property. The checkbox can only use the value checked and an emtpy string. Setting the value to checked makes it checked. You could alternatively use `element.checked=true;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('body').on('click','.category',click);

function click(){
  $('.category').each(function(i,element){
    var state = $(element).prop('checked');
    $(element).prop('checked', state ? '' : 'checked');
  });

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a test over your code, you will see that the way you are trying to grab the elements is not correct. Class "category" does not exist. What you have is  "category-desktop". SO if you test like this:

```
alert($( 'input' ).hasClass( "category" ));//False
alert($( 'input' ).hasClass( "category-desktop" ));//True
```

I think you are trying to do this:

```
$('body .category-desktop').on('click',function(){
alert("click ok");
    //run your function
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yruhL69v/4/

But to finish the code I need to understand if you want to click over any check box, or over any place on the body,or any element that has category-desktop indise body .